# WPF Mvvm Light - Checkbox and updating entity

Tags: wpf, data-binding, checkbox, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I'm having some strange behavior in my WPF application.  Why is it that this xaml will check or uncheck the check box:

```
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Driver.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

and if I UPDATE a record, it works.  It will pase true or false and update the field in the database which is a BIT data type.  If I try to create a new record for the table it does NOT work when trying to insert in to the database.  It throws an Entity Validation Error which says 'false' isn't allowed.

Comment: is `false` a `BIT` ?

Comment: Obviously not, but why is it working for checking/un checking the box initially?

Comment: implicit converter would be my guess ... I do remember that I had some issues with `Checkbox`es in the past though ...

Comment: Silly question now.. but do bool datatypes in C# support 1/0 ?

Comment: if you try : `bool a_bool = 1` It'll complain. You can use `Boolean.Parse(string_here);` , but `string_here` should be "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

**Standard MVVM-Way**: In your ViewModel for you record you should have a property with type `bool` in the setter you then can convert the `bool` to int, bit or anything you like. In the getter you have to convert your model type into `bool`.

**Not So Standard Way**: If you bind your model directly, then you might consider using an `IValueConverter` implementation to convert to the data type you require.

The distinction of the "standard" and "not so standard" way is made based on the binding. Although, you can bind the model directly - and in some cases this is quite OK - adding an additional ViewModel gives you greater flexibility when dealing with changes - both in the view and the model.

However, depending on your data access method the mapping between bit and bool will be performed automatically (e.g. EntityFramework). For this you need to declare your field as bool and the underlying database field as bit.